# Photoshop changes colors when I save my edit or merge layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, save, merge

I'm going to save an edit with multiple layers, curves, and mask layers. However, when I save the file some of layers do not apply properly and the saved file has huge differences from the picture I see in Photoshop.

Some people proposed first merging the layers, then trying to save it, but it did not work. When I merge layers the color starts to change. It should be noted that some layers contain different blending modes and mask layers.

Do you have any idea on what should I do?

Thank you in advance.

[image: after saving]

[image: before saving]

Comment: Are you viewing things at 100%?? If you are zoomed out, especially with adjustment layers, there's some anti-aliasing for the screen preview taking place. This *often* makes things look different at 100% compared to 75% or 50%.

Comment: Using *Dissolve* blend mode perhaps? I answered a (now closed) question about that [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/98118).

Comment: Hi. Which blend modes did you use?  Can you show us what the problem is?  A screenshot perhaps showing the arrangement of layers. Are you viewing the image at 100%? It's really hard to answer this without more information so I'm voting to close it for now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey Billy and others. I use Hue and Subtract blending modes. But I started to merge layers one by one, and first problem occurs when I merged a curve layer with mask layer.

Comment: Try doing all layers in one go, either: Layer > Merge Visible, or create a new layer from visible using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+E

Comment: Merge visible does not work correctly too.